# How to exempt a tag from HTMLpurifier?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm currently running some code with HTMLPurifier. However, there's one tag type we want left as-is.

I've looked through questions and docs, and haven't been able to find a clear answer... how do I exempt a specific tag from HTMLPurifier?

I'm looking for something along the lines of...

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', $HTML_Allowed);
$config->set('ExemptHTML', "img,form,pre");
```

Comment: I don't think what you're asking is possible with HTML Purifier, since its entire premise is that it takes all HTML apart, analyses it based on what it knows, and then reconstructs the HTML based on what it knows. You can teach it to know *specific* attributes (and even *specific* non-standard tags and their attributes), but as far as I'm aware, there's no way to tell it "accept all attributes with all possible values on this tag".

Comment: Chances are you wouldn't even really want that - e.g. `onclick` is almost surely not an attribute you want to allow on an `<img>` tag! (Although if it is, HTML Purifier is probably not the right tool for what you're doing? It's a bit hard to guess.) Can you explain your use-case a little more? :)

Comment: Actually, I am cleaning for XSS, but there's other code running that verifies script tags elsewhere. I'm not *removing* script tags, but I am *verifying* that the ones that are there are valid, so I'm not needing HTMLPurifier to catch XSS if its just in a script tag. That's not the only way to fire XSS, just the easiest, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but it turns out you can write a class that extends the particular schema with a _tagname on the parent and register it, and create a new validator tailored to your passthrough (ended up switching to targeting an attribute for more atomic control, but it should work for either, hypothetically).

```
if (!class_exists("HTMLPurifier_[something]scheme_[mytag]")){
    class HTMLPurifier_[something]Scheme_[mytag] extends HTMLPurifier_[something]Scheme{
        function __construct()
        {
            $this->[required_variable_for_passing_its_category] = true;
        }
        public function doValidate(&$uri, $config, $context) {
            return true;
            // Or, alternatively, you could actually do some validation here.
        }
    }
    HTMLPurifier_[something]SchemeRegistry::instance()->register(new HTMLPurifier_[something]Scheme_[mytag](), $config);
}
```